# Clicking on the <td> in AngularJS, textArea appears and I would like to automatically adjust the height of the td

Tags: html, angularjs

I have written the following HTML code.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="status" >status</th>
        <th class="date">date</th>
        <th class="tag">tag</th>
        <th class="msg">msg</th>
        <th class="management"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>ready</td>
       <td>2014.01.06 16:05</td>
       <td>Test</td>
       <td>Hello
           <div class="tag-container" ng-show="hideButton">
                        This area is comment area
           </div>
       </td>
       <td><span class="head-logo" ng-click="hideTagContainer()" ng-class="{'head-logo': hideButton ,'head-logo folded': !hideButton}"></span><input type="button" class="delete" value="Commit" ng-click="popupDelete()"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>notify</td>
        <td>2014.01.06 16:05</td>
        <td>Msg</td>
        <td>Hello This is test2!</td>
        <td>
            <span class="head-logo" ng-click="hideTagContainer()" ng-class="{'head-logo': hideButton ,'head-logo folded': !hideButton}"></span><input type="button" class="delete" value="Commit" ng-click="popupDelete()">
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

When I try to run the hideTagContainer change the height value of the `<td>`.

```
scope.hideButton = false;
scope.hideTagContainer = function () {
    scope.hideButton = !scope.hideButton;
};
```

How Will I need to change the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-class, or ng-stype with different style for the td. If the container appears, set a bigger hight value.